# Convert my generator to a generator comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

A question for the functional programming ninjas. Here's my generator:

```
def get_interesting_line(file,*searches):
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if all(search in line for search in searches):
                yield line
```

I have a suspicion this could be turned into a generator expression. My head tends to hurt when I try to make them, though. Is it possible?

EDIT: Here was my attempt, which didn't work (yielding a generator object):

```
def test(file, *searches):
    with open(file) as f:
        yield (line for line in f if all(search in line for search in searches))

lines = test('myfile')
next(lines)
```

Comment: python 3. searches is an iterable container of strings.

Comment: anyone care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: You're blatantly asking for people to give you teh codez?

Comment: I didn't originally include my attempt because I thought it was pretty lame. But I guess I was close.

Comment: still don't understand the downvotes- i think it's a good question that helped me find out about something i didn't know before (`yield from`). this website can be pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code didn't work, because

```
yield (line for line in f if all(search in line for search in searches))
```

turns your function into a generator, which yields another generator (formed by generator expression).

What you need is [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) (Python 3.3+):

```
yield from (line for line in f if all(search in line for search in searches))
```

Comment: nifty! is there a python 2 option as well?

Comment: @RickTeachey as mentioned in the answer, just remove `yield`, more specifically, you already have a generator expression, just return it, instead of yielding.

Comment: @RickTeachey I'd collect all matched lines to a list and `return` the result (or iterate over it and `yield` every element)

Comment: i normally would as well, but if the file is a couple gigs of data, i prefer the lazy method.

Comment: if you make searches a set you can use `line for line in f if searches.issubset(line.rstrip().split())`